# How can I export a sharepoint online list with version history enabled to excel?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, pnp-powershell, export-to-excel

I have enabled version history on my custom list.
Now when i do an export to excel all the multiple text fields don't show  any data at all.
How can i get it to export all the fields with data and the versions

I have tried the following below
By adding

> &IncludeVersions=TRUE

to the end of the url

```
/sites/XXX/XXX/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={5DD9E118-476E-41BF-AB5E-D1CB30D77F51}&View={9C91EA6E-BE1E-4169-A89D-2CF5BFA2F36F}&RowLimit=0&RootFolder=%2fsites%2fSite%2dApps%2fBOY%2fLists%2fBoyApps&IncludeVersions=TRUE
```

But when i load the url to the browser and i just get an xml dump file called :- owssvr.xml :(

Any ideas how to get the data into excel or something readable?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This might get you started: https://modery.net/retrieving-an-items-version-history-and-changes-with-pnp-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export the version history, you will need to use PowerShell. The export to excel feature in fact gives you a data connection, which enables you to check the list in Excel. Simply we cannot use OOB way to export version history.

Here are some scripts for your reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/01/sharepoint-online-export-list-version-history-to-excel-using-powershell.html

[https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-get-all-sharepoint-list-item-versions-using-client-side-object-model-both-for-custom-list-and-document-library#:~:text=In%20CSOM%2C%20basically%2C%20there%20is,List%20or%20a%20Document%20Library](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-get-all-sharepoint-list-item-versions-using-client-side-object-model-both-for-custom-list-and-document-library#:%7E:text=In%20CSOM%2C%20basically%2C%20there%20is,List%20or%20a%20Document%20Library).

[https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95eb0764-6974-4031-9359-8b017d2d4a76/export-list-items-along-with-their-versions-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral#:~:text=To%20export%20SharePoint%20list%20item,%22C%3A%5Ctemp%5CInvoice_VersionHistory](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95eb0764-6974-4031-9359-8b017d2d4a76/export-list-items-along-with-their-versions-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointgeneral#:%7E:text=To%20export%20SharePoint%20list%20item,%22C%3A%5Ctemp%5CInvoice_VersionHistory).